# How to tag docker image with jenkins pipeline parameter?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have a Jenkins pipeline. A stage with build image is as below:

```
stage('Build image'){
       sh 'docker build -t myImage --file $WORKSPACE/build/Dockerfile .'
            }
```

I want to add 'BUILD_NUMBER' jenkins variable to tag the image.

Is the below approach is correct? Or any other way?

```
stage('Build image'){
       sh 'docker build -t myImage:${BUILD_NUMBER} --file $WORKSPACE/build/Dockerfile .'
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me:

```
stage('Build image'){
       sh 'docker build -t myImage:${BUILD_NUMBER} --file $WORKSPACE/build/Dockerfile .'
            }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

can you try something like this :

```
       sh 'docker build -t myImage:${env.BUILD_NUMBER} --file $WORKSPACE/build/Dockerfile .'
```

i remove one ':' and also add env before BUILD_NUMBER can be variant according to your jenkins